# I am getting this error when i try to find a RecyclerView by id

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM9Tw.png) private lateinit var recv:RecyclerView

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    recv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mRecycler)
```

Comment: Hover your cursor over it and it will show you the error message that explains the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import following:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```